# Change temp data directory on unxutils on Windows doesn't working

Tags: windows, sorting, csv

I use sort.exe from [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to sort large csv files (40GB) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The sort works fine but I cannot change the temporary data directory.

What I've tried:

- using \ and / in paths
- surrounding with ' and " the temp dir path
- setting environment variables like TEMP and TMPDIR
- using the parameter T as well as --temporary-directory=DIR

I'm running as administrador, and have full permissions on the intended temp folder. The temp files are always being written on C:\ instead of the temp dir setted.

An example of what I'm executing:

C:\unxutils\sort.exe -t; --temporary-directory=c:\tmp -k1,1g -k2,2g C:\stage\input.csv -o C:\stage\input.sorted.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that [gnu coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) is an alternative that works.

Unfortunately, the binaries for windows are outdated. The workaround was to [download git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and pull the binaries from (installation directory)\usr\bin